# Will base64 encoded value exceed 65,535 characters

Tags: base64

I am planning to convert pdf files to base64 encoded and save them in the database.

My DB column is `text` type.

**Will `base64 encoded` value exceed 65,535 characters if pdf file is big?**

Comment: They’re not going to be less than the file size for sure, so if the file is larger than 49151 bytes then obviously yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not storing it in my database but instead save the file on the server and save the filename in the database.

Answer (score 2):

[Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) maps the input bytes (8 Bit) to a 6 bit representation. That means, with a 4 character string in base64 encoding, you can encode 4 * 6 = 24 bits, which equals 3 byte of the unencoded original input. Therefore the result of the encoding will be 33% bigger than the input. And base64 encoding has no limits, so a 1MByte input will give you a 1.33MByte output.

As Sami mentioned in the comment, 49151byte input will result in 65535 bytes output.