# Using Go's base64.StdEncoding.Decode() method: how to choose the size of the destination byte slice?

Tags: go, base64

I'd like to use `Decode` (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.Decode) to decode a slice of bytes and was wondering, given this method signature,

```
func (enc *Encoding) Decode(dst, src []byte) (n int, err error)
```

how to choose the size of the `dst` slice of bytes to be just big enough to capture the output. For example, this snippet (adapted from https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.DecodeString)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "c29tZSBkYXRhIHdpdGggACBhbmQg77u/"
    dst := make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(dst, []byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", dst)
}
```

prints

```
some data with  and ﻿
```

However, if I choose the size of `dst` too small (e.g. `0`), I get an `index out of range` panic:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
encoding/base64.(*Encoding).decodeQuantum(0xc000084000, 0x1193018, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000080f30, 0x20, 0x20, 0x4, 0x10, 0x10, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/encoding/base64/base64.go:352 +0x567
encoding/base64.(*Encoding).Decode(0xc000084000, 0x1193018, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000080f30, 0x20, 0x20, 0xc000080f38, 0x105779d, 0x10b16e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/encoding/base64/base64.go:500 +0x5aa
main.main()
    /Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/base64_decode.go:11 +0xb4
exit status 2
```

How can I choose the size of `dst` based on the size of `src` to reliably decode the input?

Comment: the decoded result is 33% larger than the encoded string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026008/will-base64-encoded-value-exceed-65-535-characters/59050780#59050780)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `base64.DecodedLen` to find the maximum size you need to decode the input, and then use the `n` returned from `Decode` to find out how long it really wrote to that slice.

Answer (score 1):

Following [jps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps)'s comment and reading up at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64, since the input is encoded in 8-bit bytes but the output is in 6-bit (radix-64) ones, the output needs to be 8/6 = 4/3 times the size of the input. So this should work:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "c29tZSBkYXRhIHdpdGggACBhbmQg77u/"
    dst := make([]byte, len(str)*len(str)/base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(str)))
    _, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(dst, []byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", dst)
}
```

based on the implementation of `DecodedLen()` which under normal circumstances returns the length of the input times 3/4:

```
// DecodedLen returns the maximum length in bytes of the decoded data
// corresponding to n bytes of base64-encoded data.
func (enc *Encoding) DecodedLen(n int) int {
    if enc.padChar == NoPadding {
        // Unpadded data may end with partial block of 2-3 characters.
        return n * 6 / 8
    }
    // Padded base64 should always be a multiple of 4 characters in length.
    return n / 4 * 3
}
```

In the end, though, I ended up just converting the input to a string and using `DecodeString()` since that already embodies this logic.