# How to calculate the encoded Base64 Message

Tags: networking, network-programming, base64

A message with 3000 bytes gets encoded using the scheme Base64. What will be the size of the encoded message? What is the answer and how do I Calculate the size of it, with what formula?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026008/will-base64-encoded-value-exceed-65-535-characters/59050780#59050780

Comment: @jps didn;t quite got it

Comment: each base64 character encodes 6 bits, so to encode 3 bytes (24 bits) you would need 4 base64 characters, that's an increase of 33%

Answer (score 0):

3000 bytes are 3000 * 8 = 24,000 bits

There are 64 Base64 symbols, so each symbol encodes 6 bits (2^6 = 64). Therefore, we need 4000 Base64 symbols to send the data.

Each Base64 symbol takes up one byte (8 bites), so sending 4000 Base64 symbols requires 4000 bytes

Comment: To make sure I understood, a message encoded with Base64 of 50000 bytes will be 400.000bits?

Comment: 50,000 bytes are 400,000 bits which require 66,666.6 (so 66,667) Base64 symbols, which take up 66,667 bytes.